# Thymeleaf : How to access elements of hash set one by one?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, hashset

I am creating a hash set as follows.

```
public Set<InventoryPriceRange> getPriceRanges() {
        if(priceRanges == null){
            priceRanges = new HashSet<>();
        }
        return priceRanges;
    }
```

Now I want to access its elements one by one using thymeleaf. I am currently doing it like this

```
th:value="${IR.priceRanges[1]}
th:value="${IR.priceRanges[2]}
th:value="${IR.priceRanges[3]}
```

Output just shows this instead of the value.

```
com.vlclabs.adsops.domain.deal.InventoryPriceRange@1f1f61a4
```

And this is the code under com.vlclabs.adsops.domain.deal.InventoryPriceRange. This is used to set the values of the hash set.

```
    private Long id;

    private double lowerLimit;

    private boolean equalLowerLimit;

    private double upperLimit;

    private boolean equalUpperLimit;

    private double price;

    public InventoryRow getInventoryRow() {
        return inventoryRow;
    }

    public void setInventoryRow(InventoryRow inventoryRow) {
        this.inventoryRow = inventoryRow;
    }
}
```

I'm new to thymeleaf. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Your Set is empty. And a HashSet has no defined order, so accessing its elements by index doesn't make much sense. And we have no idea what "garbage" is, and what you expect instead. If you have a collection of stuff to show, why don't you use a loop?

Comment: did several edits in the question and showed how the data is added to the hash set. Please see.

Comment: This is not garbage at all. It's what the toString() method of your class, which is inherited from Object, returns: the name of the class followed by the hashCode of the object. What *else* do you want to display? If you want to display, let's say, the price, then... display it: `${IR.priceRanges[1].price}`

Comment: Yes It works now. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mechanism which says about the accessing the collection in thymeleaf is as:

```html
<tr th:each="message : ${messages}">
    <td th:text="${message.id}">1</td>
    <td><a href="#" th:text="${message.title}">Title ...</a></td>
    <td th:text="${message.text}">Text ...</td>
</tr>
```

Explain: ${message} - replace this with your collection 
Explore on the above lines and make changes
And the collection name as above should be your modelattribute name which is getting return.